# Value of $f(x,y,z)= x+y+z$ if $z$ decreases as $x+y$ increases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We have three continuous variables $x,y,z$ and we know their behavior.

1) When $x+y$ increases, $z$ decreases.

2) When $x+y$ decreases, $z$ increases.

We have a function $f(x,y,z)= x+y+z$.

What we can say about the functional value when

1) $x+y$ increases?

2) $x+y$ decreases?

Comment: @NateEldredge I couldn't find any journals or papers try to solve such problems.

Comment: I don't think you will find this in any journal.

Comment: @Gloughloubarbaki   
we know that partial derivatives of (x+y) with respect to z and that depends on z only

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

You can't say anything. Let's consider a special case of your hypothesis and assume $z$ is completely determined by $x+y$, so there is a function $g$ such that $z=g(x+y)$, and $g$ is decreasing. Then $f(x,y,z)=g(x+y)+(x+y)$, so the behaviour of $f$ is determined by the behaviour of $g + \mathrm{Id}$.

However, without any further information on $g$ except that it is decreasing, $g + \mathrm{Id}$ may be increasing, decreasing, or neither.

So even in the special case where $z$ is completely determined by $x+y$ you can in general say nothing about the behaviour of $f$ depending on variations of $x+y$.

Comment: we know that partial derivatives of (x+y) with respect to z and that depends on z only.

Comment: @Norman : you are right but this is even worse, even in the special case I posted about you can't say anything

Answer (score 0):

Note that, $x+y+z=k$( Since, $x+y$ increases, $z$ decreases & vice versa)

$f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$

$z>z'$

$f(x,y,z')=x+y+z'$

But every $f(x,y,z)=k$

*$Case:1$*

$x+y>(x+y)'$

Either, $x>x'$, $y>y'$ or both of them.

$f(x',y,z)=f(x,y,z)$ implies value of $y+z$ decreases.

$f(x,y',z)=f(x,y,z)$ implies value of $z+x$ decreases.

$f(x',y',z)=f(x,y,z)$ implies value of $z$ decreases.

Similarly, you can try for $Case:2$

Comment: There can be cases where $x+y$ ioncreases if $z$ decreases, and the reverse, and yet $x+y+z$ is not constant.

Comment: We can consider that since the two conditions are given. Right?

Comment: If $z=(1/2)^{(x+y)}$ then $z$ increases when $x+y$ decreases, and also $z$ decreases when $x+y$ increases. And $x+y+z$ is not constant in this case.